# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasterio' even It is installed from the cmd

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, rasterio

I'm using Python 3.7.2 and Pycharm as an IDE. I'm trying to import the rasterio packages but its gives me an error in Pycharm ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasterio'. Even I have installed it from the cmd with the GDAL as it is mentioned here https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html . Apparently all the packages that I want to work with has the same issue with Pycharm as even i installed them via the cmd it gives me always that error. I tried to install the rasterio package from Pycharm just as I did with Numpy but It gives me a GDAL problem. For The numpy it worked just fine.  Thanks.